# Rails4 - Combining identical orders into batches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need some architectural advice. I have an ordering system. My users can order products from a variety. Each order can have only one type of product, but the quantity may differ. Now the Order feed looks something like this:

```
Order 1 - Product#1 - Qty: 5, created_at: 01/01
Order 2 - Product#5 - Qty: 12, created_at: 01/02
Order 3 - Product#7 - Qty: 1, created_at: 01/05
```

However when a user orders several identical products at different times, the list looks somewhat like this

```
*Order 1 - Product#1 - Qty: 1, created_at: 01/01
 Order 2 - Product#5 - Qty: 12, created_at: 01/03
*Order 3 - Product#1 - Qty: 3, created_at: 01/05
```

This creates unwanted duplication in my views (and sometimes the manager has to call several times to order stuff) and I am struggling to figure out how to combine these orders into a batch, so I would get something like this:

```
*Order 1,3 - Product#1 - Qty: 4 (1+3), created_at: 01/01, 01/05
 Order 2 - Product#5 - Qty: 12, created_at: 01/03
```

Would love to hear some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I would join the products with the orders ordered by product_id.
I would walk through the collection and display one line if the product_id changes.

This way the whole report could be done with a single query instead of 1+n query. :)